# Java better way to delete file if exists

Tags: java

We need to call `file.exists()` before `file.delete()` before we can delete a file E.g.

```
 File file = ...;
 if (file.exists()){
     file.delete();
 }
```

Currently in all our project we create a static method in some util class to wrap this code. Is there some other way to achieve the same , so that we not need to copy our utils file in every other project.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Starting from Java 7 you can use [deleteIfExists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists%28java.nio.file.Path%29) that returns a boolean (or throw an Exception) depending on whether a file was deleted or not. This method may not be atomic with respect to other file system operations. Moreover if a file is in  use by JVM/other program then on some operating system it will not be able to remove it.  Every file can be converted to path via `toPath` method . E.g.

```
File file = ...;
boolean result = Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath()); //surround it in try catch block
```

Comment: @ZhaoGang actually you do have to try/catch this. Take a look at the signature from the JDK:
`public static boolean deleteIfExists(Path path) throws IOException {
        return provider(path).deleteIfExists(path);
}`
You can pass the throws declaration upwards but try using this inside a stream without try/catch and compile it without errors :)

Answer (score 42):

```
file.delete();
```

if the file doesn't exist, it will return false.

Comment: It returns false if the file can't be deleted not if it does not exist.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't already exist, it can't be deleted, which means this should return false.

Answer (score 15):

There's also the Java 7 solution, using the new(ish) Path abstraction:

```
Path fileToDeletePath = Paths.get("fileToDelete_jdk7.txt");
Files.delete(fileToDeletePath);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This method returns true if the file was deleted by this method; false if the file could not be deleted because it did not exist.

Comment: @insanely_sin: Files.delete() is a void method. You're thinking of myFile.delete()

Answer (score 6):

Apache Commons IO's [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) offers `FileUtils.deleteQuietly`:

> Deletes a file, never throwing an exception. If file is a directory, delete it and all sub-directories.
>   The difference between File.delete() and this method are:
>
> - A directory to be deleted does not have to be empty.
> - No exceptions are thrown when a file or directory cannot be deleted.

This offers a one-liner delete call that won't complain if the file fails to be deleted:

```
FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File("test.txt"));
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have the file inside a dirrectory called uploads in your project. bellow code can be used.

```
Path root = Paths.get("uploads");
File existingFile = new File(this.root.resolve("img.png").toUri());

if (existingFile.exists() && existingFile.isFile()) {
     existingFile.delete();
   }
```

OR

If it is inside a different directory this solution can be used.

```
File existingFile = new File("D:\\<path>\\img.png");

if (existingFile.exists() && existingFile.isFile()) {
    existingFile.delete();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this type of function, maybe this will interests some of you ...

```
public boolean deleteFile(File file) throws IOException {
    if (file != null) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();

            for (File f: files) {
                deleteFile(f);
            }
        }
        return Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below statement to delete any files:

```
FileUtils.forceDelete(FilePath);
```

**Note:** Use `exception handling` codes if you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Commons **FileUtils.deleteDirectory()** or **FileUtils.forceDelete()** to log exceptions in case of any failures,

or **FileUtils.deleteQuietly()** if you're not concerned about exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Generally We create the File object and check if File Exist then delete.

```
File f1 = new File("answer.txt");
if(f1.exists()) { 
    f1.delete();
}
```

OR

```
File f2 = new File("answer.txt");
f2.deleteOnExit();
```

If you are uses the Apache Common then below are the option using which you can delete file and directory

```
File f3 = new File("answer.txt");
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(f3);
```

This method throws the exception in case of any failure.

OR

```
 File f4 = new File("answer.txt");
 FileUtils.deleteQuietly(f4);
```

This method will not throw any exception.

Answer (score -3):

This is my solution:

```
File f = new File("file.txt");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    f.delete();
}
```

Answer (score -8):

```
  File xx = new File("filename.txt");
    if (xx.exists()) {
       System.gc();//Added this part
       Thread.sleep(2000);////This part gives the Bufferedreaders and the InputStreams time to close Completely
       xx.delete();     
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `System.gc()` in the process? It's completely useless in this context, and only causes noise.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP *knows* this works but is asking for a better technique that doesn't require an `if` check every time and just add boilerplate code every time.