# Delete temporary file after successful download java

Tags: java

First I'm writing the excel file in a temporary location then I'm downloading it from that location. Here is the code:

Here I'm writing excel into some temporary location and returning the location of that file:

```
public String parseExcel(Map<String, List<String>> data) {
   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   Sheet sheet1 = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
   .
   .
   .
   var tmplocation = File.createTempFile("SampleTemplate", ".xlsx");
   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(tmplocation);
   workbook.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();
   return tmplocation.getPath();
}
```

And here I'm downloading that file from that location:

```
try {
    filePath = parseExcel(data);
    file = new File(filePath);
    return Cors.add(request, Response.ok(file).header("Content-Disposition",
           "attachment;filename=\"SampleTemplate.xlsx\"").header("Content-Length ", file.length())).allowAllOrigins().auth().build();
} catch() {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

**To delete the temporary file I added finally block and in finally block I'm getting the file, but it didn't worked. It said FileNotFound Exception**

How can I delete this temporary file after the successful download of the file?

Comment: You haven't shown the delete code, and does your upload run asynchronously (so is deleting file before Cors is finished?)

Comment: file.delete() i have added in finally block but server is throwing error filenotexception

Comment: @user10144071 Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The [`deleteIfExists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists-java.nio.file.Path-) method of `java.nio.file.Files` can help you.

> Deletes a file if it exists.

> As with the delete(Path) method, an implementation may need to examine the file to determine if the file is a directory. Consequently this method may not be atomic with respect to other file system operations. If the file is a symbolic link, then the symbolic link itself, not the final target of the link, is deleted.

> If the file is a directory then the directory must be empty. In some implementations a directory has entries for special files or links that are created when the directory is created. In such implementations a directory is considered empty when only the special entries exist.

> On some operating systems it may not be possible to remove a file when it is open and in use by this Java virtual machine or other programs.

You may also wish to use [`createTempFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) to create your file.

For reference:

- [Java better way to delete file if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599965/java-better-way-to-delete-file-if-exists)
- [Java Tutorials - Deleting a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html)

Comment: I want to delete the file after the successful download of the file.  I've added the delete file in the finally block but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete a file?  You might think of `file.delete ();`.

You can find that it actually exists by reading the documentation for the `File` class and scanning the list of methods.  In doing so, you will see things that you will remember later on, so it is a great way to expand knowledge.

Documentation is useful.

If you use an IDE like Eclipse, you can get a context-sensitive menu of suggestions, usually a list of possible methods you might use.

Comment: I want to delete the file after the successful download of the file. I've added the delete file in the finally block but it didn't work

Comment: Hard to know why without a minimally reproducible example.