# How to control file generation using Freemarker template process

Tags: java, freemarker

I am using freemarker template to generate a file. The ftl template has java API call and when there is an any exception from java API, i want to avoid writing the file in between template processing. See below code

```
templateFileName --> freemarker template file name (.ftl file)
templateFilePath --> freemarker template file path (.ftl file)
outputFilePath --> output file path

FileTemplateLoader fileTemplateLoader = new FileTemplateLoader(new File(templateFilePath));

MultiTemplateLoader tmpltLoader = new MultiTemplateLoader(
    new TemplateLoader[] { fileTemplateLoader});



// Set to Configuration
freemarkerConfig.setTemplateLoader(tmpltLoader);
freemarkerConfig.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
freemarkerConfig.setWrapUncheckedExceptions(true);
freemarkerConfig.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
freemarkerConfig.setFallbackOnNullLoopVariable(false);

Template template =
    freemarkerConfig.getTemplate(templateFileName.substring(templateFileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, templateFileName.length()),
        StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());

// write output into a file:
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(outputFilePath))) {
  template.process(input, fileWriter);
}
catch (TemplateException e) {
  new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath).close(); //This causes only the file empty. But i dont want to write the output file 
}
```

Comment: Delete the file if exists? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599965/java-better-way-to-delete-file-if-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a `StringWriter` to `Template.process`, and then if there was no exception, write the resulting `String` into the file. However, be sure that the output is small enough to fit into the memory. Otherwise write into a temporary file, and move it to the final place if there was no exception.

Comment: Thank you @ddekany it works. We would check memory usage